# Fastest DNS library for python

Tags: python

What library is the fastest to make hundreds of DNS queries in multi-tasking.

I've googled round DNS libraries for python. I found that adns is said to be fastest. 
But it's not Windows-compatible. Are there any cross-platform compatible DNS libraries for python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twisted's DNS library is cross platform. Whether or not it's the "fastest" is debateable but Twisted performs very well on the whole. I'd be surprised if it couldn't saturate your I/O link.

One point of note though: Twisted uses asynchronous I/O rather than multi-tasking to achieve concurrency. Async I/O is a very good mechanism for handling concurrent queries but it requires a different programming style from the typcial threaded approach. The learning curve can be steep but it's fairly short and, in my opinion, it's well worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I've learnt Twisted is an entire networking library. Can you suggest me what to use Twisted and when not to use it?

Comment: Sure. Personally, I always look to it first. Asynchronous design based on Deferreds is a powerful programming paradigm. In my experience, Twisted has usually proven to be a good choice. It's not a panacea though so the evaluation must still be done on a case by case basis.